# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Code: 80070020, VBScript

Tags: vbscript

When I run my vbscript, it says(In Windows Script Host):

---

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Test.vbs

Line: 34

Char:1

Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Code: 80070020

Source: (null)

---

How would I be able to fix this? Also here's the script...

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objShell, objFile
Dim strDirectory, strFile
strDirectory = "c:\Folder"
strFile = "\Hidden.bat"
If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
End If


If objFSO.FileExists(strDirectory & strFile) Then
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
End If

set objFolder = nothing
set objFile = nothing

Const fsoForAppend = 8

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim objTextStream
Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Folder\Hidden.bat", fsoForAppend)

objTextStream.WriteLine "attrib ""Folder"" +s +h"

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run """C:\Folder\Hidden.bat"""
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: What's your aim ? I guess you want to hide `c:\folder` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without creating any batch file to hide your folder :

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO,objFolder,strDirectory,Command,Result,objShell
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strDirectory = "C:\Folder"

If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
End If
set objFolder = nothing

Command = "Cmd /c Attrib +s +h "& DblQuote(strDirectory) &""
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Result = objShell.Run(Command,0,True)
Set objShell = Nothing
'****************************************************************
Function DblQuote(str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'****************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

> Closes an open TextStream file.
>
> ```
> object.Close
> ```

From Help.

You need to close it after writing to it before using it.